# Is jPlayer compatible with PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, jplayer

I have a web app that uses jPlayer as the backbone of a playlist music player. This works properly on desktop in Google Chrome, but not in PhoneGap (porting to Android) and I've narrowed the problem to jPlayer. Does anyone know if PhoneGap supports jPlayer?

Also: I know there is a duplicate question: [jPlayer and PhoneGap Build compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938154/jplayer-and-phonegap-build-compatibility), but nobody answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Audio tag is broken in the Android WebView. If I remember correctly jPlayer makes use of the Audio tag so it will fail as well.

I'm working on a monkey patch over at:

http://macdonst.github.com/corinthian/

Comment: If I only want the audio tag functionality while using Corinthian, do I need to build the project or can I just include the Corinthian Javascript file in my own project? The reason I ask is that I keep getting errors while running 'ant jar', and if I don't have to do that it would save me a lot of time trying to fix the compile errors.

Comment: Yeah, you'd only need the .js file if you only need the Audio monkey patched.

Comment: Including the Javascript file in my project seems to make my project fail, is there any reason that should happen?

Comment: No, it really shouldn't fail. What error are you seeing? Perhaps we should take this offline over IM or email.

Comment: I'm not seeing an error in LogCat in eclipse, the application just hangs. If you'd like you can email me at vince.delricco@videon-central.com, and hopefully we can get the issue sorted out.

Comment: Hi Simon. I was wondering if you were still willing to troubleshoot this with me. I just need to know if I should start to find an alternate solution to my problem, or if you think Corinthian can still help me out. Thanks for your time.

Comment: this is not correct player does work in phone gap web view on Android and iOS have been using it since last year.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, jPlayer just wraps HTML5 audio/video functionality. Some tablet devices (iOS safari) have problems/flaws/limitations with media tags, if something won't work it will be a problem of HTML5 audio/video tags not jPlayer.